# Android: Get an attribute's value from an XML item

Tags: android

Is there an easy way to grab a attribute value from an xml item in your Java class definition? I'm looking for something like this:

// In xml layout:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/MyXMLitem" android:textColor="#000000" />
```

// in Java Class definition

```
String some_text_color;
some_text_color = R.id.MyXMLitem.attr.textColor; // I'd like this to return "#000000"
```

I know you can grab similar xml attributes from the converted objects using getters/setters like View.getText()... I'm just wondering if there's a way to grab an xml attribute right from the item itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views take the XML values and store them into class level variables in their constructors so it's not possible to get values from the object itself once the layout has been created.

You can see this in the source of the View object at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java
 if you search for AttributeSet (which is the object used to pass the XML layout values to the constructor).

Comment: Thanks Al - I wasn't sure if there was native Android functionality  that would grab a xml attribute value right from an layout file. Now I know!

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/MyXMLitem" android:textColor="#000000" />
```

You can use [getCurrentTextColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getCurrentTextColor()).

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewbyId(R.id.MyXMLitem);

String color = Integer.toHexString(tv.getCurrentTextColor());
```

It returns **ff000000** instead of **#000000** though.

Comment: Very cool, this is one of the implementations I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XmlResourceParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/XmlResourceParser.html) to read data straight from XML resources.